# How to get values from two table with subqueries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have two tables names are feed, and friendship....

friendship table has these fields..toid which the session user id, fromid which is the friend id, and status that may be 0 or 1, and the feed table contains id,post_user_id which is the feed poster id, and contents. Now i want to get the feed from the feed table only from my friends i am able to get feeds from my friends but i can't get my own feed , when i put my own id in the condition the query is executed but the result empty. i tried these

```
    SELECT * FROM feed WHERE `post_user_id` IN (Select fromid from 
     gr_user_friendships where toid = 47) ORDER BY 
      post_date_time DESC
```

/****This query giving only the friends records not mine to get my records also i put my own id in the condition agains****/

```
   SELECT * FROM feed WHERE `post_user_id` IN (Select fromid from 
     gr_user_friendships where toid = 47) and `post_user_id` = 47 ORDER
      BY post_date_time DESC
```

/*This time this results empty**/

I also tried this with inner join no success at all

Comment: If you want to get both your friends feeds and your own, use `OR post_user_id = 47` instead of `AND`

Comment: Are you using `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM feed WHERE post_user_id = 47 or 'post_user_id' IN 
(Select fromid from gr_user_friendships where toid = 47) ORDER BY 
 post_date_time DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn`t it work with an OR instead of the AND?

```
SELECT * FROM feed WHERE `post_user_id` IN (Select fromid from 
 gr_user_friendships where toid = 47) OR `post_user_id` = 47 ORDER
  BY post_date_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second query:

```
SELECT * FROM feed WHERE `post_user_id` IN (Select fromid from 
     gr_user_friendships where toid = 47) and `post_user_id` = 47 ORDER
      BY post_date_time DESC
```

just replace `and` with `or`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT * FROM feed INNER JOIN (Select fromid from 
 gr_user_friendships where toid = 47) WHERE 'toid' =  47 and `post_user_id` =    47 ORDER
  BY post_date_time DESC
```

Comment: answer need modification ?